# Source Documentation for Android 12 (SDK 31) is missing in Android Studio. Is there a fix/workaround?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

With the newest Android 31 SDK (Android 12), the documentation for the SDK is missing.

The SDK Manager shows that the "Sources for Android X" exists for SDK 30 but is missing for 31:

[image: "Sources for Android 30" exists but not for SDK 31]

The documentation displays nothing:

[image: Documentation returns nothing]

Other used versions: Build Tools Version 31.0.0, Gradle 7.2, Android Gradle Plugin 7.1.0-alpha08

Is there any way to either get the documentation for SDK 31 or at least get the documentation for SDK 30 whilst still using 31?

---

Side note:

What usually works for loading a missing documentation is opening a Java/Android class, where you will see this popup at the top of the class:

[image: Missing documentation on Android class (PopUp)]

Normally the "Download"-option would download the documentation and fix the problem. In this case however, it returns an error:

[image: Packages Unavailable]

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution that lets me use the documentation for the Android SDK 30 (whilst still using SDK 31) until they supply the actual documentation for the SDK 31:

Go into *C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources* (or a different directory where your SDKs are saved) and copy the contents of the folder named "android-30" (or the highest version you've got) into a newly created folder named "android-31". That's it.

Addition: Since it seems like it's not working for everyone: I'm using the newest Canary version of Android Studio, with everything (Gradle, libraries etc.) as up to date as possible.

Comment: It's not working for me. Did you do anything else?

Comment: I don't think so. Did you follow the steps and the documentation still didn't show up? Or did you have problems along the way?

Comment: Yes, I copied android-30 folder into android-31, then cleared caches and restarted android studio and nothing happened. Android studio still can not see the 31 api documentation

Comment: Hm, then I'm not sure. I'm also using the newest Canary version of Android Studio, not the stable release. Maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: You could also try going into the module settings of your project (select the uppermost folder in your project structure and press F4) and see what your "Android SDK location" is set to. Maybe it's different from mine.

Comment: I didn't look at your sdk location and went straight into mine :) Maybe the reason is really that you are using canary. But I can not try using that at the time. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can attach sources from android SDK 30 as @CodingBeing mentioned, but there are extra steps to make it work.

- Go into your SDK location (probably `C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`) into `sources` folder
- Copy `android-30` directory as `android-31`
- And now you should open a `android-31/package.xml` with your favourite text editor and carefully replace all the `30`s to `31`s (3 places)
- Also, do the same to `android-31/source.properties`(1 place)

And it should finally work, at least in stable Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 2.

Answer (score 1):

The SDK 31 sources are available now through the Android Studio SDK manager or [dl.google.com/android/repository/sources-31_r01.zip](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sources-31_r01.zip)

Comment: This is full of stubs, no actual source code in there.

Comment: This source is not complete. For example wifiinfo class does not exist. In api 30 this class is available

Answer (score 0):

It can be built from the upcoming SDK source directly. I have automated the process using Github Workflow, here: https://github.com/ni554n/sources-for-android-sdk

Comment: It would be better if you can provide the code fragment that solve the problem in your answer rather than a link to your repository, as link can be broken/moved.